# Java game socket network router issue

Tags: java, sockets, networking, router

Good day, 
I have a java game that I want to play with a friend over network, I have implemented Sockets and tested the game on my pc using localhost as address, but was unable to connect to the external ip of my pal's pc, presumably due to us both being behind routers.
Here is the code of host/client:

CLIENT:

```
try {
    socket = new Socket(inputHostIp(), 5555);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

SERVER:

```
try {
    hostServer = new ServerSocket(5555);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
listenForUserConnection();

while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = hostServer.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue; 
    }
    joined(socket);
}
```

The exception I am getting now is

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
On trying to init I/O:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
java.net.Socket.getInputStream/java.net.Socket.getOutputStream
```

I have set up port forwarding with the chosen port number (5555) linked to the internal ip on both our machines.

What are my options for getting this to work?

ADDENDUM:
We have also tried using Hamachi to create a virtual LAN, but there seems to be an issue with that - we can’t ping one another even through that, it diagnoses with an issue -

Tunnel:
    VPN domain's tap device is down
Local results:
    Adapter configuration: 
            Cannot get adapter config
    Traffic test: Cannot complete test
Peer results: [160-056-951]
    Adapter configuration: OK
    Traffic test: Inbound traffic blocked, check firewall settings

I have tried shutting down firewalls, hamachi issues changed to just ‘cannot get adapter config’, but otherwise no results. 
On my pc, however, I got a version of windows that doesn’t seem to display Firewall setting properly, if you think it’s likely an issue, can you tip me on how to test my firewall?

Comment: What Windows versions are in use?

Comment: We both have Windows 7, but mine is old and "custom"

Comment: Before using the VPN, you did use the public IP (the one of the router that is visible in Internet), not the local IP, right? I guess so, but just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, we used external ip's as shown by 'my ip' query in google :)